# Magento 2 How to check Price Type?

Tags: magento2, currency

File location

```
<magento dir>\vendor\magento\module-directory\Model\Currency.php
```

In Magento we have "finalPrice" & "oldPrice"

Can anybody tell me how to check Price Type? Can we use

```
$priceCurrencyObject = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface');
```

Not sure

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is:
In the  `\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml` , use `$block->getPrice()->getPriceCode()` to get the price type string.

Or any function you can find which return object implements the `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface`, you can call the `getPriceCode()` to get the price type.

Or if you have the product object, just call $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice()->getPriceCode();

Hoping it's helpful to you.